# Visualize PolygonZ shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, 3d

Is it possible to see the 3D shapes of the PolygonZ shapefile?

I have Qgis2treejs plugin installed, but it shows the shapes as if they are Polygon so 2D shapes).

Comment: What do you expect to see? A sample image would be helpful. Normally, 3D Map Viewer ("View > New 3D Map View") displays a polygon, with high z value, higher than the others. Moreover, it displays any vertex, with high z value, higher than the other vertices.

Comment: I have a triangular polygon, where all three vertices are in 3D space. Here is the file: https://gofile.io/?c=7SKuMV

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need any plugin to see PolygonZ shapefile in 3D. Built-in **3D Map Viewer** ("View > New 3D Map View") shows polygons in 3D based on Z values of its vertices.

Note that 3D view currently doesn't support unprojected/geographic coordinate systems, so you need to convert shapefile unprojected CRS to projected one or change CRS of the "QGIS Project" (no need to change shapefile's crs) using "Project > Properties... > CRS". In CRS tab, search or select any suitable projection under projected coordinate system.

- Choosing projected coordinate system:

[image]

- Modifying 3D options for the layer. (I added a point layer to see vertices in 3D)

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Kadir!
When I try to enter the 3D view I get the following message: "3D view currently does not support unprojected CRS." How do I project it?

Comment: You can change CRS of  the Project (no need to change shapefile's crs) using "Project > Properties... > CRS". In CRS tab, select any suitable projection under  projected coordinate system. You can use "World  Mercator (EPSG:54004)", "EPSG:3857" or "EPSG:102100".I will add another animated gif.

Comment: Thank you @Kadir! This solves my problem.
So essentially the reason why I couldn't see the polygon in 3D in both 3D view and Qgis2treejs is because the CRS was not projected?

Answer (score 7):

It seems that PolygonZ doesn't work in Qgis 3D view but working pretty nice in qgis2threejs plugin for me:

[image]

Just make sure that your shape is a real PolygonZ file.

Comment: PolygonZ works in QGIS 3D Map Viewer by a few settings.

Comment: Cool! Did not work for me for some reason.

Comment: Hi @FelisPimeja,
I can't make it work. I have the same settings as you do, but the polygon still looks flat. Here is the shapefile: https://gofile.io/?c=7SKuMV
Also what I don't understand is that QGIS 3.10 shows this shapefile as "MultiPolygonZM", but QGIS 2.6 describes it as “PolygonZM”.

Comment: @marco, edit: working for me on both QGIS 3.10 and 3.11 versions. Just be shure to use projected coordinate system as Kadir-Şahbaz mentioned